# Obtaining the limiting probability

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory

It is required to obtain the limiting probability

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}P\left (\frac{X_1-X_2+\cdots+X_{2n-1}-X_{2n}}{\sqrt{n}} \leq x \right )$$

The random variables are IID with variance $1.$

**My approach**

The variance of the $X_1-X_2+\cdots+X_{2n-1}-X_{2n}$ will be $2n$. One $\sqrt{n}$ is already in the denominator. Hence, we would divide the both sides by $\sqrt{2}$. So, the Variable $\frac{X_1-X_2+\cdots+X_{2n-1}-X_{2n}}{\sqrt{2n}}$  will be a standard Normal. But, how to proceed from here.

I don't have answers available. That's why I am getting difficulty in this problems.

Any help?

Comment: So you need the probability that a standard normal is less than $\dfrac x {\sqrt 2}. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy you meen $\Phi (\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}})$

Comment: Write $Y_1=X_1-X_2$, $Y_2=X_3-X_4$, etc., and apply the Central Limit Theorem to the $Y_k$.

Comment: @RAHUlJHa : Yes -- I mean the probability that a standard normal is less than $\dfrac x {\sqrt 2},$ and that probability is $\Phi\left( \dfrac x {\sqrt 2} \right). \qquad$